# Dynamically updating individual cells in a data grid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have an observable collection of Taxis. The Taxi class has properties like Taxi_No, Name, Current_Locn, Bill_Amount.

I have bound the observable collection to a wpf data grid. As a taxi is added or deleted from the collection, the changes are reflected in the data grid. But as the taxi moves through the city the location of the taxi changes(Current_Locn) and so does the bill amount. However, these changes are not dynamically reflected in the grid.

I understand that observable collection keeps only track of changes to the collection. But, how do I keep track of individual properties of each data item in the collection? Should I implement INotifyPropertyChanged on each property? and how do I bind it to the grid in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the Taxi class.